# No jQuery support in Eclipse Helios? -> jquerywtp 0.40 breaking Eclipse Helios JSDT core from WST

Tags: javascript, eclipse, helios

When i run the jquerywtp jar with:
'java -jar jqueryWTP0.40foCn.jar', on my org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.1.2.v201009011528.jar
file, the result is a broken .. 'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.1.2.v201009011528.jar'

after trying to install it, i cannot start any Javascript project, getting the message that my jsdt core package is broken.

while running jquery wtp, i get this in my tty console:

META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:223)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:177)
        at com.langtags.js.util.IOUtils.appendToJar(IOUtils.java:323)
        at com.langtags.js.ui.ExportJarDemo$GenerateAction.actionPerformed(ExportJarDemo.java:268)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
myloginname@sammy100:~/Downloads$ mc

What could cause this error, i would like to have Jquery support in Eclipse!?

Comment: Probably directory for 'Jar File' is the same as 'Output Dir'.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your issue, but JSDT has recently fixed a few problems it had parsing jQuery.js.  The fix is available in JSDT 1.2.3 which is included in the WTP 3.2.3 download. It's also available in the development stream in JSDt 1.3.0 in WTP 3.3.0.  The WTP downloads are at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's probably just unclear to me how to start with jQuery in a Eclipse - Javascript project. Can you please confirm that, in order to use jQuery, i simply add the jquery.js to my eclipse project? I cannot add the library (like DOM is included with Eclipse), to eclipse?

Comment: Adding jQuery.js to the Eclipse project works fine for me. I do have a different environment than you though. I either deploy to an Android device with PhoneGap or load an index.html directly into a browser for testing. I'm not using Eclipse for the DOM.